# Force angle of photo taken ANDROID

Tags: android, camera, angle, gyroscope

I want take photo and try to do it on the inclination of 180 degrees +/- 5 degrees, in other degrees camera should be blocked.
In brief I want force take photo horizontally to floor (or close to it).

What is the easiest way? I should use gyroscope? The problem is that angle must be checked all the time that degree is good.

Answer (score 0):

Use orientation sensor. Framework reports to you when value of sensor is changed, so as long as you keep sensor registered for usage, you will have actual device orientation.

Retrieve `SensorManager` by calling `context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)`. Also look at [Android Orientation sensor for rotation the 3D cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499862/android-orientation-sensor-for-rotation-the-3d-cube)